# Why can't I hide the top border of a textfield?

Tags: java, javafx

So recently i have been working on a project and I need textfields to get the username and the password of the user.

I have tried using *-fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 0, 0;

- to hide the border but the border on top still persists.

Here is the code:
   `-fx-background: whitesmoke; -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 0, 0; -fx-background-radius: 0 ;`

And here is the result. As you can see the border on top still persists:

[image]

Comment: I don't think the background color for a text field uses `-fx-background`, so the "border" you're seeing is the linear gradient from the default `-fx-background-color` for a text field. Try replacing `-fx-background: whitesmoke;` with `-fx-background-color: whitesmoke;`.

Comment: Is the following what you want? `* {
 -fx-primary-color: #007acc;
 -fx-secondary-color: #4B6EAF;
 -fx-grey-color: #b9b9b9;
    
 -fx-focus-color: -fx-secondary-color;
}

.text-field {
 -fx-accent: -fx-primary-color;
 -fx-background-color: -fx-grey-color, white;
 -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
 -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.text-field:focused {
 -fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color, white;
}`

Comment: The above code is from `https://dx.dragan.ba/javafx-textfield-custom-css/`

Comment: @SedJ601 sorry for not answering your comment, I was away. Your style was exactly what I was looking for! If you can, please make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a style I got from https://dx.dragan.ba/javafx-textfield-custom-css/. It gets rid of all the borders except the bottom border.

**CSS**

```
* {
    -fx-primary-color: #007acc;
    -fx-secondary-color: #4B6EAF;
    -fx-grey-color: #b9b9b9;
    
    -fx-focus-color: -fx-secondary-color;
}

.root{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color, white;
}

.text-field {
    -fx-accent: -fx-primary-color;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-grey-color, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.text-field:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color, white;
}
```

**Output**

[image]